# How to use "All" for an array property in a class using MongoDB C# Driver?

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have this Class for example:

```
public ClassA{
   public string name;
   public ClassB[] BS;
}
public ClassB{
   public StatusEnum Status; // Status is enum "One,Two,Three,Many"
}
```

**I want to write a query that will return one object that does not contain any "Three" enum.**

I tried to write this query but got an exception:

```
FilterDefinition<ClassA> filterDefinition =
                Builders<ClassA>.Filter.Where(
                    ca => ca.BS
                            .All(bs => bs.Status != StatusEnum.Three));
return _mongoDbHelper.EvaluationSessions
            .Find(filterDefinition)
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

This is the exception that I got:

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
>   MongoDB.Driver.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Unsupported filter:
>   All({document}{ClassB}.Where((Convert({document}{StatusEnum}) !=
>   2))).

Is there a better \ proper way to write queries for array in a class? I'm aware of the "ElemMatch" function but I can't figure it out how to use it with the "All" linq.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a working example of what you need:

```
    MongoClient client = new MongoClient();
    var collection = client.GetDatabase("test").GetCollection<ClassA>("test");
    var b1 = new ClassB() { Status = StatusEnum.One };
    var b2 = new ClassB() { Status = StatusEnum.Two };
    var b3 = new ClassB() { Status = StatusEnum.Three };
    collection.InsertOne(new ClassA { BS = new[] { b3 } });
    collection.InsertOne(new ClassA { BS = new[] { b1, b2 } });
    collection.InsertOne(new ClassA { BS = new[] { b1, b2, b3 } });
    // using LINQ:
    var x = collection.Find(a => !a.BS.Any(bs => bs.Status == StatusEnum.Three)).First();
    //using plain MongoDB query syntax:
    var y = collection.Find("{\"BS.Status\": {$nin: [" + (int)StatusEnum.Three + "]}}").First();
```

Comment: Thanks!,
 I'm not sure why, but using negation of Any (Which is the same as All) work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to perform a Mongo DB query operation with an enum that is not supported at the DB level. you can cast the enum to int so your query will work with the mongo native driver.

Enums cannot be [deserialized](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-723)

It is not translated by the c# Mongo DB driver. (some linq operation like enums are not supported).
for example:

```
FilterDefinition<ClassA> filterDefinition =
                Builders<ClassA>.Filter.Where(
                    ca => ca.BS
                            .All(bs => (int)bs.Status != (int)StatusEnum.Three));
return _mongoDbHelper.EvaluationSessions
            .Find(filterDefinition)
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: _"that is not supported in the DB level"_ - that's correct, so it's translated by the driver level (to string, int, or whatever you want), or at least supposed to.

Comment: @CodeCaster I tried using your example, casting the enum to int but I'm getting the same exception..., So it doesn't work :\

Comment: I'm not sure why, but using negation of Any (Which is the same as All) work as expected.